# Java Synchronize issue: PrintWriter slower than other operations

Tags: java, synchronization, printwriter

I am pretty new to thread programming in Java, and I am currently building an application which, among other, takes a number of SQL scripts and calls them.

For each file it performs the call and, in case that some Exception is thrown it catches it and writes the concerning info into a log file by using a PrintWriter constructed with a FileWriter.

Of course, all this is carried on by a for loop.

The problem comes when the file writing which is slower than the rest of the operations is not completed successfully: the process finishes before the writing is over, so the file ends up incompleted.

I have tried my way by using synchronized blocks of code, wait() and notify() methods, but no success yet. I attach the excerpt of code:

```
    boolean waiting_for_end_of_file_writing = true;

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(FICHIER_LOG_ERREURS_SQL, true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

    for(int j = 0; j < input_paths_sql.length; j++){

        System.out.println("Script " + m + " dont " + input_paths_sql.length
                + " avec nom " + oftp.get_locals()[j]
                + " à exécuter");
        try {
            Generic_library.Call_Fichier_SQL(oftp.get_locals()[j], 
                    ojdbc.get_sybase_connection());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Form_table_clients.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            pw.write("Exception en fichier " + oftp.get_locals()[j] + "\r\n");
            ex.printStackTrace(pw);
            pw.write("\r\n");
            Logger.getLogger(Form_table_clients.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        m++;
    }
    synchronized(pw){
        pw.write(" -----------------  END OF UPDATE PROCESS ----------------- \r\n");
        waiting_for_end_of_file_writing = false;
        pw.notify();
        }
    synchronized(pw){
        try {
            while(waiting_for_end_of_file_writing)
                pw.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Form_table_clients.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return success;
```

So this goes:
- Generic_library.Call_Fichier_SQL() takes the path and the Connection object to the DataBase, and uses them with a CallableStatement to call the script

My goal is to stop the thread BEFORE IT REACHES the line of **"return success"** which finishes the method until pw has completed all the writing and eventually performed the line which goes

**pw.write(" -----------------  END OF UPDATE PROCESS ----------------- \r\n");**

Otherwise, the log file, as foresaid, ends up incomplete.

Thanks for any help you could give me. Likewise, if anyone can come up with some idea to bypassing the problem (may be by ussing some thread safe way to write into the file, for instance) it could make too.

Comment: As @PeterLawry has said, you need to flush a PrintWriter, which has an internal buffer. But a better solution is to replace the PrintWriter with a real logging framework, such as Log4J or LogBack.

Answer (score 0):

When you finish writing, you need to flush it, or preferably close() it.  If you leave the application running it can flush and clean up the resource itself (at some random time) but you should always do this yourself so you know it is done.

In short, always close Stream/Reader/Writer/Statement/Connection/ResultSet when yo are finished with them. (In fact anything which can be close() )

In your case, I would remove both synchronized blocks and use `pw.flush();`

While println() is not fast, it should be 10x - 100x faster than an SQL query from an JDBC database.

Comment: It works. Such a long while just looking around just to find such a simple answer :-/

Thanks a million, @PeterLawrey and kdgregory